# Parcelable class returned to parent activity is null

Tags: android, android-intent, null, parcelable

For this bookstore app I am making while learning android development in a tutorial.I been struggling with this problem for a good 6 hours. For some reason when I setResult on the child Activity, when I check the toString of the Book Parcelable class, it prints out what is expected in logcat. I start the Activity for Result in the parent by doing this in onActivityforResult:

```
            Intent addIntent = new Intent(this, AddBookActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(addIntent, ADD_REQUEST);
```

and then send the Parcelable class Book back (done in child activity) by doing

```
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra(BOOK_RESULT_KEY, newBook);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            Log.i("intent get", returnIntent.getParcelableExtra(BOOK_RESULT_KEY).toString());
            finish();
```

In this case toString() returns the title and the price of the book when entered in the app correctly.Here is how I retrieve the intent in the parent activity:

```
if(requestCode == ADD_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Book newBook = intent.getParcelableExtra(AddBookActivity.BOOK_RESULT_KEY);
            Log.i("book", newBook.toString());
            shoppingCart.add(newBook);
```

However it always prints out "null null" instead of "TITLE_OF_BOOK PRICE_OF_BOOK". Numerous posts on stackOverflow have describe a similar issue but nothing worked. I tried using bundles when sending and receiving the intents as well.

I am pretty sure my Book class has parcelable implemented properly, but here it is for reference. Author is a parcelable class too.

```
public class Book implements Parcelable{
int id;

public String title;

public Author[] authors;

public String isbn;

public String price;

public Book(int id, String title, Author[] author, String isbn, String price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.price = price;
}

private Book(Parcel in){
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.authors = in.createTypedArray(Author.CREATOR);
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.isbn = in.readString();
    this.price = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeTypedArray(authors, 0);
    dest.writeString(isbn);
    dest.writeString(price);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Creator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Book(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Book[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
 public String toString() {
    return title + " " + price;
}
}
```

I am really not sure why it is always showing null, the whole idea of sending intents and using parcelables seemed easy to understand.

EDIT: when adding Log.i("book", newBook.title), this error shows up:

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {...BookStoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:println needs a message
```

and then the error points to that Log line.

It seems that all the attributes of Book are set to null for some reason when received but not when sent.

Comment: Try adding `Log.i("book", newBook.title);` and `Log.i("book", newBook.price);`. See if it shows something.

Comment: It returns the error shown in the edit. Same with price too.

Comment: Your previous and new error is same. Its just says that you can't print a message which is null. In this case `newBook.title` and `newBook.price`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why is that the case? In the child activity the Log.i("intent get", returnIntent.getParcelableExtra(BOOK_RESULT_KEY).toString()) shows the correct info that I entered in the app (the title and price). However once I do finish(), nothing is in the intent/the parcelable has null variable when received by the parent.

Comment: `newBook` is not null. Its properties are. I really can't say why.  I need to read more about Parcelable.  :(

Comment: Thats why its returning "null null". Darn. Thank you!

Comment: Parcelable objects are flattened while passed to different activities and unflattened after.  You must write your data to the parcel, and read it from the parcel in the same order.

Comment: Try implementing your model class `Book`, by the interface (Serializable)[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html]. This way you don't need to override any methods. Let me know if this works. And for your information, if a class representing a single entity, in your case a `Book`, the modifiers of the fields should be `private`. And also there should be a (default constructor)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_constructor] and (getter and setter methods)[] for the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Book object is unable to reconstruct itself due to the fact that you are reading values from the parcel in a different order than you wrote them.

In your `writeToParcel()` method, you're writing title second, and authors third. Yet, in your parcel constructor, you're reading authors second, and title third.  You need to read values from the parcel in the order you wrote them.

Try that out, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: That did it! I can't believe I missed that.  Many thanks for helping me solve this problem.

Comment: No problem, this one has definitely got me before too :-)